# save new mongoose schema for each element of array using ecmascript 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am looping through an array and creating a new mongoose schema, adding two fields, and then saving it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var newUsers = new UserList({
        email: myArray[i],
        uuid: uuidv4()
    });
    UserList.save(function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
    });
}
```

### Question:

how can I achieve this using ecmaScript 6 best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your solution by using map method and mongoose [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) method.

```
const bulkData = myArray.map(email => new UserList({ email, uuid: uuidv4()}));
UserList.insertMany(bulkData, (error, docs) => {});
```